# How to break joomla loadObjectList into 3 column

Tags: php, arrays, joomla, jtable

I'm trying to divide joomla loadObjectList into 3 parts and display as 3 column. But i could not do it.

This is my joomla sql code

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery('SELECT title,introtext,images FROM #__content WHERE catid = '.$catID);
$articles = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach($articles as $article){
$title = $article->title;
$description = $article->introtext;
$imageObj = json_decode($article->images);
$imagepath = $imageObj->image_intro; 
}
```

i want to add this values into 3 columns.

like this

[image]

Comment: Several questions: 1. Where is this code, in your extensions model or controller or view? 2. What version of Joomla are you using? 3. Is each of your numbered blocks meant to be an article? 4. If yes, to #3 are you wanting to represent variable heights (aka mosaic style) as shown in your diagram?

Comment: @cppl i created separate module for this.I'm using joomla 3.yes i'm getting  this images from articles.yes i want like that. for that i want to add that images to bootstrap col-md-4 block. pleas help me. i do not have any idea about it. :(